# Getting error while compiling a simple class program

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am getting the error while compiling the following simple C++ class program .

***Error*** : **'ptr_code' undeclared (first use this function)**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class company
{
  public:

  int code;
  int *ptr_code;

  company(int i)
  {
          ++count;
          code=i ;
          ptr_code = &code; 
  } 

};

int main()
{
company c(10);
company *ptr_c = &c;
cout<<<<"\n";
cout<<"\nCompany codes : \n"<<ptr_c->*ptr_code<<"\n"<<ptr_c->code<<"\n";
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Please help me out in the same while the variable **ptr_code** is declared as integer pointer with public scope specifier , while the  **ptr_c->code** is working fine.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ptr_c->*ptr_code` should be `*ptr_c->ptr_code`. `ptr_c->*ptr_code` would be valid if `ptr_code` was a variable of type pointer to company data member.

Answer (score 3):

Change `ptr_c->*ptr_code` to `*ptr_c->ptr_code`

And

```
cout<<<<"\n";
```

to

```
cout<<"\n";
```

You are using a variable `count` in constructor `company` which is not part of the class, neither it's declared. So it's going to give you an error.

Answer (score 1):

use `*ptr_c->ptr_code` instead of `ptr_c->*ptr_code` look into [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)